# Assign random integer numbers to an ArrayList using stream

Tags: java, random, java-stream

I came up with this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> randomIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
randomIntegers = Stream.generate(Math::random).map(n -> n * 10000)
                                              .mapToInt(Double::intValue)
                                              .limit(10)
                                              .boxed()
                                              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Since I am pretty new to streams: **Is there something** more elegant i.e. **shorter** while at least equally readable (still using streams)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rarely actually care whether the result should be stored into `ArrayList` or any other `List` implementation. So probably it's better to use `Collectors.toList()` instead of `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`. Furthermore, it's common practice to use

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

In this case you can write simply `toList()`.

Using `Random.ints(long, int, int)` as source, you can generate 10 random numbers in the range of `0..10000` in the single call. Putting everything together, you will get:

```
List<Integer> randomIntegers = new Random().ints(10, 0, 10000).boxed().collect(toList());
```

Note that depending on further usage of these numbers, you may probably consider storing them into array instead:

```
int[] randomIntegers = new Random().ints(10, 0, 10000).toArray();
```

This way it's not only shorter, but also more efficient (both CPU and memory-wise) as does not require the boxing.

Comment: Excellent answer +1 for suggesting a solution without boxing.

Answer (score 1):

More elegant with shorter and more readable using `java.util.Random` and `IntStream`

```
Random random = new Random();
random.ints(10, 0, 10000).boxed().forEach(randomIntegers::add);
```